# What are ways to handle too many database connections?

Tags: mongodb, database

I have a website that caters to daily fantasy sports players and on days with big slates (i.e. a lot of games), the site gets hammered before the lineups get locked. "Hammered" in my case means 50-100 concurrent users, which I'm sure doesn't sound like a lot, but it seems to kill my database host (Mongolab). During "normal" operations, the max number of open connections I see is less than 500, but during these peak times, there can be upwards of 10,000 open connections!

I think what happens is that users open the site, see that it is not responding quickly enough, and then they proceed to open a bunch more sessions thinking one of them will work. This causes the downward spiral.

Last week I added multi-key indexes which helped quite a bit, and I thought had "solved" the issues. But today the site got hammered and even the new indexes haven't proved to be enough. What else can I do?

Comment: What is the meaning of "before the lineups get locked." ?  I would have thought maximum three or four database connections per logged in user at maximum.  Are you using a framework for the site?

Comment: Two big questions: 1) Are you using connection pooling? 2) Are you closing your connections after executing your queries?

Comment: I'm using NodeJS and Mongo for the backend. No connection pooling (not sure how this works in Mongo). If it's possible, would that help? And to answer the last question, in theory, the connections are being closed. But I think if the query doesn't finish they stay open. Maybe I need a timeout?

Comment: @zipzit Players have to turn in their lineups (rosters) by a certain time each day. So of course everybody does this at the last possible minute.

Comment: I think my code lacks connection pooling. I better implement this before anything else.

Comment: @EvanZamir - let me know if that works and I will add it as an answer. I think the main thing is to ensure you are closing your connections after you are done. Try not to open multiple concurrent connections within your code.

Comment: Thanks @gmiley. I'm trying a node module called mongo-factory that is supposed to automatically take care of connection pooling. Hopefully this is the fix!